# git pull files from a bare repo

Tags: git, repository

I have a bare repository in my remote server. Files get uploaded on the remote server, now I would like to sync or pull those uploaded files to my local repository.

I usually run `git push website` in order to deploy my local committed files, now I would like to do the opposite. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that users upload files to the web server, and they get saved to the file system, and now you want to retrieve them using git?

Comment: that's right, basically bring those files to my local server/repository.

Comment: How are thye "uploading" the files?  `git push`?

Comment: right, if I do `git pull website` I get: `Already up-to-date`, and I think this is due to the same reason Ryan mentioned. Are there any other solutions to this?

Comment: @Andy: files get uploaded using a web interface uploader.

Comment: If it's a bare repo, How are you deploying your website with `git push`?  Even if it's not bare, you would still need to log into that machine to update your working directory.  There are too many holes in what you are asking. We need more info.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by running `git pull GIT_SOURCE` where GIT_SOURCE is in the form git@github.com:facebook/credits-api-sample.git

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this, then what you're trying to do isn't possible. A bare repo is characterized by not having a working copy in the file system. Therefore no file on the disk of a bare repo can be part of the repo, and you can't pull it as a result. If it were a non-bare repo and files were uploaded into the directory where the working copy is checked out, you'd still have to add and commit the file(s) there before you'd be able to pull them from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git pull` ([manpage](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html)).

```
$ git pull REPO_URL
```

What `$REPO_URL` is depends on your setup. Maybe

```
$ git remote show website
```

will give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is a pull of you bare repository, here is an example

at your website host you have two repositories

- repository_bare.git (bare repository)
- repository_webapp   (non-bare repository)

at your local copy
 - local_repository

1) you push at your local_repository and upload the modifications at your repository_bare.git
2) you pull the repository_bare.git from local_repository

```
git pull repository_bare.git
```

This will merge the modifications from your bare to your local repository

Here is a link with more information
http://book.git-scm.com/3_distributed_workflows.html