# Pulling from a bare git --repo that's configured to push to server

Tags: git, git-pull, git-bare

first question here (yay me).

I just started my first job as a Developer a couple months ago, and have recently set up my (very small) company on VCS. We're not using GitHub, but rather pushing local commits to a bare repo, and then that repo has a post-receive hook that deploys the code on the server. This is working well for me individually, and I'm also able to clone the bare repo in order to set up new users with the codebase.

My questions are about pulling to update our individual local repos with what's on the server. It's similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852388/git-pull-files-from-a-bare-repo), but I'm not sure how to format the SOURCE mentioned there given that our repo isn't on GitHub, and haven't had any luck searching elsewhere. I've tried pulling from my local repo when I know there are minor difference, but after the pull my files don't reflect the live code, yet I still get the message "already up to date."

Once we're able to pull, I'm curious how differences will be merged. For instance, let's save dev1 and dev2 have the same, current version of the live code from the server. Then dev1 starts working on something that spans several days. During that time, dev2 makes some small changes and pushes them live. What happens if some of dev2's tweaks happen to be working with the same lines/files that dev1 is working on, and dev1 on tries to pull before he's finished all of his changes?

Through all of my searching on Google and such I've seen plenty of things saying that the bare repo makes all of this stuff easier etc., but I've not found anything explaining exactly why that is.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Not sure the fact that the repo was set up as bare has an impact in this case. Most of the times git figures things out and everything just works.

However if two developers change the same lines of code, one of them will have to fix some conflicts.

This book here has helped me understand how git works. First 3 chapters are usually enough, very easy to read. If you want to get in more depth, read the other chapters too: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: Git is not about *files*, but rather about *commits*. (Commits then contain files, but the files contained in a commit—which amounts to a full snapshot of *every* file, per commit—are frozen for all time, and not actually usable; they have to be un-archived first, which is what checkout / switch does). When you grab stuff from some server repository, regardless of which server, you're grabbing new *commits*. Developers end up making, and then merging, *commits:* permanent (mostly) frozen snapshots of all files. The result of a merge is another commit.

Comment: If you don't like something about the commits you have, the general rule here is: "add another commit". Despite every commit having a full snapshot of every file, most commits are *tiny*, because they don't actually have the files: Git has some very clever sneakiness where file contents get *shared* across (and even within) commits. This is enabled by the read-only aspect.

Comment: The files you see and work on, when using Git, are in your *working tree* or *work-tree*. Most repositories come with a work-tree. Note that the files here are *copied out of* Git, but aren't actually *in* Git while you work on them! The thing that makes a "bare repository" special is that it lacks a working tree.

Comment: @Gec Thanks for the resource! I'll definitely be reading that.

Comment: @torek Thanks for the info! That clarifies a few things with the way 'files' are stored.